# Server domain resolves, subdomains don't

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, domain, subdomain

I set up a vanilla Ubuntu Server installation,

Other computers on the network can access its webserver with http://servername/

But when I try to access sub domains (e.g. http://something.servername/) it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`servername` is not a domain, it's a hostname (computername) so you can't have a subdomain of it.  Your domain name would look something like `mydomain.com`.

If you have a domain like `mydomain.com` and servername is a part of it (that is, has a dns host record in the domain), then the first URL you have would be `http://servername.mydomain.com`

If you want to have a subdomain then it needs to first be created in dns.  Let's call it `subdomain.mydomain.com`.  At that point you then need a host record in the subdomain to have a valid URL.  Something like `http://servername.subdomain.mydomain.com`.

Comment: I don't think so. I just put something.servername into all 'hosts' files; a bit of a hack but it works.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ok.  Understand, though, that your machine will interpret `servername` as the domain name and `something` as a host name.  You have not created a subdomain.  This could mess with your apache config.